# ios - why do most instructions say "uncheck copy items into the destination folder" when adding libraries to project?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios6

It seems that the files should indeed be copied into the destination folder...no? What am I missing here?

Most of the time various tutorials seem to say that button should be unchecked.  But it seems like that is better to check.

Could someone please explain the distinction to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just about project management. If you download some files from the web say, then add them to your project, you probably want to copy them. Then you can delete the originals and you will still have a copy in your project. Alternatively, you download a folder of code and move it to a folder on your machine where you keep 3rd party code. Now when you add the code to your project you probably do not want to copy the code so that in the future if you fix a bug in the code it is available in all projects where you're using that (shared) code.

It's very much about personal preference and how you're managing the code files on your machine, in and between projects.

Not copying == leave the files where they are.
Copying == save the files inside the project so I don't loose them.

Comment: thank you. It is kind of what I thought but they make it feel so complicated :)